# What type should I use for a methods `self` argument?

Tags: python, mypy

If I'm using `mypy` on my project, what type should my methods self object be given?

```
from typing import List

class Example:
    def __init__(self, arg1: List[str]) -> None:
        pass
```

Comment: I don't think you need to set a type to `self`, as it is never seen by anyone calling your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing, leave it as is.

That is what I could tell from their documentation:
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/class_basics.html?highlight=self